# Can I install Ubuntu into VM using a Live USB?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, livecd

I want to set up an Ubuntu VM in my machine, but downloading the ISO is too much. I do have a Live USB containing Ubuntu. How can I install it?

Comment: +1 Good question. Why don't you try it, and then tell us how it went as an answer? It'll teach you something and gain you rep **and** help other people with the same question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, without knowing what flavour of VM software you use, its a bit difficult to say. Both [Vmware player](http://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2010/06/10/booting-from-a-usb-stick-in-vmware-player/) and [virtualbox](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?p=14648) don't support it out of the box however. It should be pretty easy to get around - you'd need to grab a bootloader that would bootstrap booting off the USB key.

[Plop](http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanagers.html) bootmanager should do the trick - its a bootloader you can download as an ISO, is small, and supports booting off various media even if they system its on doesn't directly.